# Docker Mysql8 native_password and sql_mode

Tags: docker-compose, mysql-8.0

I'm having an issue moving to Mysql8 in my Docker compose.

I want to use the mysql_native_password authentication plugin AND I want to remove all the sql_modes.

Here is the relevant section from my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mysql-server:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0.30
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    command: --sql_mode=''
```

These commands both work if used individually.
But using both doesn't work, it sets one value but not the other.
I've tried various ways to concatenate the strings that failed to set either.

I cannot connect to mysql when I try this often seen solution

```
command: >
  bash -c "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  && --sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'"
```

also tried

```
command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password", "--sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"]
```

Do you know how I can set both?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this seemed to work

```
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password", "--sql_mode="]
```

That is with no single quotes inside the double quotes.  Perhaps you could escape the single quotes (especially if you want to set one or more modes) ... I didn't try that.

Hope this helps someone from banging your head against the wall as many times as I did.